# why does a graph of a function with a finite image has Jordan measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

We have not even talked about lebesgue integration, just introduction to measure theory. This came up in our textbook, and i have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: It's contained in a finite number of lines....

Comment: not sure i get what you are saying

Comment: The graph is a subset of $\mathbb{R}\times f(\mathbb{R})$. What does this set look like if $f(\mathbb{R})$ is finite?